# which resolution images to design for different android drawables folder

Tags: android, android-layout, resources

**hey everyone**
I've been facing drawables and layout related issues for a few days....
there are drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhpdi folders in resources directory in android project
I've gone through the official android doc several times it definitely explains everything pretty well
e.g scaling ratios for ldpi(0.75), mdpi(1), hdpi(1.5), xhdpi(2)
but i couldn't find any information regarding which resolution to start with???
for example if i start designing graphics resources for xhdpi folder then which resolution i should go for???
as there are many devices out there which lie in extra high density bucket but each having different resolutions, for example

1. Nexus4 (768x1280 xhdpi)
2. Nexus 10 (2560x1600 xhdpi)
3. Galaxy Nexus (720x1280 xhdpi)

   same is the case with hdpi and mdpi bucket, lots of devices are there then which resolution images we should place in the corresponding folder????

   please guide me guys m really in trouble

Answer (score 1):

Look at @CommonsWare's answer.
I add that we are talking of dpi.

```
MDPI (160dpi)
HDPI (240dpi) 
XHDPI (320dpi)
XXHDPI (480dpi)
XXXHDPI (640dpi)
```

Then:
to convert between dp and pixels use this formula:

```
px = dp × density ÷ 160
```

Answer (score 0):

> but i couldn't find any information regarding which resolution to start with?

For the vast majority of apps, if you are worrying about resolution, you are doing it wrong.

Ask yourself how you would write this as a Web app. Browser windows can have an arbitrary number of pixels of width and height, because the user can resize those windows as she sees fit. You are not going to design distinct imagery for a 1023x805 window instead of a 1037x740 window. Instead, you are going to take some approach that can handle a reasonable range of window sizes, perhaps with alternative artwork when you jump to a new range of window sizes.

Then, take that design approach, and apply it to your Android app. Focus on screen size and density, not resolution.

> which resolution images we should place in the corresponding folder?

Resolution has nothing to do with density.

Comment: really thankfull for such a quick reply, i need to tell the graphics designer about the resolutions of graphics i need for the app what should be the answer in such a scenario if plan to support maximum possible devices (phones + tabs), also if you could recommend me some article or sample project that would be great...

Comment: @khurramengr: "what should be the answer" -- I have no idea what images these are.

Comment: well we have got PSD files of views from the client, and we need to crop images from these files some of the graphics are for buttons, menus, and tabs.......

Comment: @khurramengr: Buttons, menus, and tabs should be designed using density-independent pixels, as you would do with Web development. When exporting the actual PNG files, Photoshop or the equivalent should be able to then save those files at the right resolution for various densities (see Gabriele's answer). You do not need artwork at every density, as Android will scale artwork as needed. I would focus on high density images (e.g., `xxhdpi`), then test on lower-density devices and adjust as needed.

Comment: i think m really missing or misunderstanding some concept could you please point me to some article that explains all these things step by step that would be great

Comment: @khurramengr: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

dpi has nothing to do with resolution. The dpi system is made so that a certain image will be (about) the same physical size no matter of the screen density, for example Google suggests that Buttons should be 48dp which is (about) 9mm on ANY density, but resolutions are different on any device, and including tablets you can't really worry about resolutions.

When making an app think about how you want to look, not in exact manners, for example "I want this line to have four buttons", make a LinearLayout with four buttons and you are done! (Sometimes you may want to include a horizontalScrollView depending on the size of the buttons).

Over time you will manage to understand this better, it's a matter of practise!

Comment: thanks for your comment, in xml layouts is it good practice to define the sizes of all widgets in dps??? e.g if i define a button to be 48dp x 48dp in xml then when the system will apply this layout on a larger screen(tablet) in this case the button would be having the same physical size, isn't it??? shouldn't they be proportionally bigger on a larger screen??

Comment: when creating a button in xml, android takes care of its default size in order to be touchable. Also usually you want your buttons to be about the size of a finger (in order to be easy to touch) if it's a bigger screen then there will be more space for other views. Don't forget that the screen may be bigger but the person is always the same size :P try this link: http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html
also note that on 160dpi screen (mdpi) 1dp = 1px